# Error: HTTPS site requires a 'Referer header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent

Tags: python, http, httprequest

> You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a 'Referer
>      header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is
>      required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being
>      hijacked by third parties.

I was trying to login to a website using requests but received the error above, how do I create a  'Referer
   header'?

```
payload = {'inUserName': 'xxx.com', 'inUserPass': 'xxxxxx'}
url = 'https:xxxxxx'
req=requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(req.text)
```

Comment: Which python library do you want to use? [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)?!

Comment: Sorry I thought I had posted I am using requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in headers you want to send on your request as a keyword argument to `request.post`:

```
payload = {'inUserName': 'xxx.com', 'inUserPass': 'xxxxxx'}
url = 'https:xxxxxx'
req=requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Referer': 'yourReferer')
print(req.text)
```

Comment: A referer header is simply a HTTP url that *links* to the target page. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14. Presumably, your target website will use that information for tracking referrals -- I'm guessing for your purposes, you can just use `http://www.example.com` or any random valid HTTP URL really. However, if they're using it to whitelist a list of referring sites, then you will need to know at least one of the websites in that whitelist.

Comment: If you are going to write an crawler, be sure to sent each information necessary for login (Cookies, User Agent, ...). I hope respect the site's [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/)... ;-)

Comment: Use a network sniffer like [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) to see, what information are normally send between a browser and your target server... (do a normal login while wireshark is recording your network traffic...) On Firefox or other browsers you can also use the [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) to accomplish the same...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using this library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

If this is the case you have to add a custom header `Referer` (see section [Custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)). The code would be something like this:

```
url = '...'
payload = ...
headers = {'Referer': 'https://...'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

For more information on the referer see this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the Same error in Chrome. What I did was just disabled all my chrome extensions including ad blockers. Here after I reloaded the page from where i wanted to scrape the data and logged in once again and then in the code as @Stephan Kulla mentioned you need to add headers inside headers i added user agent, referer, referrer-policy, origin. all these you can get in from inspect sample where you will find a Network part..
add all those in header and try to login again using post it should work.(It worked for me)

```
ori = 'https:......'
login_route = 'login/....'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' , 'origin':'https://www.screener.in', 'referer': '/login/','referrer-policy':'same-origin'}

s=requests.session()
csrf = s.get(ori+login_route).cookies['csrftoken']

payload = {
    'username': 'xxxxxx',
    'password': 'yyyyyyy',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
}

login_req = s.post(ori+login_route,headers=header,data=payload)
```